# Error using developer.yahoo.com/weather with axios

Tags: axios, weather-api

In my php7.1/laravel5.5/vue.js2.5 application I want to get weather information from
https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html

But running on my local server( Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) ) running like

```
        const query = `select item.condition from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='${city}') and u='c'`;
        const location = `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=${query}&format=json`;
        axios.get(location ).then((response) => {
            alert( "response.data::"+var_dump(response.data) )
```

I got error in my browser:

```
 Failed to load https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item.condition%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%27London%27)%20and%20u=%27c%27&format=json: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local-tasks.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I created an app at https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/ with Consumer Key/Consumer Secret , but I wonder if I have to use them for my local server?
If yes, how?

Thanks!